# Richert’s theorem breaks down for $ n = 11 $

Tags: proof-verification, summation, prime-numbers

In 1949 H.-E.Richert proved (1) that every positive integer typeset structure is a sum of distinct primes. For more information please look at (2), and (3).

However, if you consider $ n = 11 $, you will see that you can't express it as a sum of distinct prime numbers.

Is there an error in Richert’s theorem?

---

**References**

(1):
Richert, H. E. (1949). Über Zerfällungen in ungleiche Primzahlen. (German). Math. Z., 52, 342-343.

(2):
http://www.cs.cas.cz/portal/AlgoMath/NumberTheory/AdditiveNumberTheory/RichertTheorem.htm

(3):
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319891?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: $11$ is a sum of distinct primes, it is already prime.  Richert's theorem allows for the "sum" to just have a single term.

Comment: Just as [lulu](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) pointed out, the theorem doesn't break down for n=11 if you allow for the "sum" to just have a single term.

However, if you allow for the sum to contain only 1 term, then shouldn't this theorem work for n>1 ?

Comment: +1 from me, a misguided but valid question is a good question!

Comment: Possibly of interest:  If you are interested in the question, I'd recommend going through the proof in detail.  It's not that bad.  I expect, but am not sure, that there is some cutoff beyond which you can require "sums" to have at least $2$ terms.  After all, it is hard to imagine that $p-2$ has a $2$ in the sum AND $p-3$ has a $3$ in the sum, and so on.  Might not be hard to establish the result.

Comment: To the earlier comment, the theorem is truly false for $4$ and $6$.  There is no getting around that.

Comment: Valera, it doesn't hold for $n = 4$ and $n=6$, since the theorem specifically says the sum of distinct primes.